# As a new developer what is the best practice when making a file with all the API requests for a specific component?

Tags: javascript

So im building a new app and was wondering what is the best practice for file/folder structuring. Should i aggregate all the functions that deal with API requests as the following code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

export function useLeads(){

  const[leads,setLeads] = useState([]);
 
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchLeads();
  }, []);

  const fetchLeads = () => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/leads')
      .then((res) => setLeads(res.data))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  };

  const addLead = (newLead) => {
    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/leads/new', newLead)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          setLeads([...leads, response.data])
        } else {
          throw new Error('Failed to add lead');
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  const deleteLead = (name,email) => {

    axios.delete(`http://localhost:5000/leads/delete?name=${name}&email=${email}`)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          setLeads(leads.filter(lead => lead.name !== name && lead.email !== email));
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };
```

or is there a better way to do it, like separate functions in a file with multiple exports or a file for each request?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I use a similar hook structure like that for my `useAuth` wrapper. I don't think your setup would be ideal for your situation. For example, you wouldn't want to fetch all leads every time you invoke `useLeads()`. I keep all my utility functions like this in separate files in `/src/lib`, each with only one default export:

```js
  const addLead = (newLead) => {
    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/leads/new', newLead)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          setLeads([...leads, response.data])
        } else {
          throw new Error('Failed to add lead');
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

export default addLead;
```

Also, don't use `useEffect()` in your fetch function. Use that in your Component script.

Here's an example of how you might use this in practice:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import fetchLeads from "@/lib/fetchLeads";

export default function DisplayLeads() {
  const [leads, setLeads] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const thisFetchLeads = async () => {
      const thisLeads = await fetchLeads();
      if (typeof thisLeads === typeof {}) setLeads(thisLeads);
    };

    thisFetchLeads();
  }, []);

  return <div>{JSON.stringify(leads)}</div>;
}
```

And your function would simply return the data:

```js
import axios from "axios";

export default async function fetchLeads() {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get("/path/to/leads/api");

    // TODO: sanity check
    return res.data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback. I will try to make the changes you suggested.

Comment: my only issue, or maybe im seeing it wrong, is how do i use the "Set.." functions in this case "SetLeads" on other functions that need it, like the "deleteLead". Do i need to declare it on every function, or is there a way to import it, because i need to declare it right?

Comment: @LazyLlama: If you're talking about state, you should declare and set that in the context of the Component you use to display the data, not in the data fetching/mutating functions.

Comment: @LazyLlama I added an example of how you might use your functions in practice to my original answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help and example provided. Im just not understanting how can i read the state of the 'leads' and use the 'setLeads' function to provide a new state in other fucntion than the one they are declared. how do i do the context you are talking about? sorry im quite new on react and javascript.

Comment: `export function fetchLeads() {
  const [leads, setLeads] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/leads")
      .then((res) => setLeads(res.data))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }, []);
  return leads;
}` i have it like this how do i use on other functions like my deleteLead

Comment: ` function deleteLead (name, email)  {
    axios
      .delete(`http://localhost:5000/leads/delete?name=${name}&email=${email}`)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          setLeads(leads.filter((lead) => lead.name !== name && lead.email !== email));

          // You can refresh the table data here or show a success message to the user
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        // You can show an error message to the user here
      });
  }; `